# How can I make this js code output to one decimal place? How do implement in MY SPECIFIC case?

Tags: javascript, math, output, rounding

This code outputs a number with many decimal places.. I'd like it limited to just one... this code gets me my desired result BUT with too many characters displayed.

I'm a total noob....

```
function oninputchange() {
$output.textContent = $input.value.split(/\s/g).map(syllable).reduce(sum)/4.7;
}
```

The results are expected... Just want fewer decimal places

Comment: I've seen these examples but I don't see how to implement in my specific case, can someone show me? I don't much care about accurate numbers.. Just care about how it looks in the display :) The simplest solution is best for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use method toFixed() for limit the decimal number to show

Comment: Tried that but didn't work... please show me how to implement in code?

Comment: This is how you can implement it:
$output.textContent = $input.value.split(/\s/g).map(syllable).reduce(sum)/4.7.toFixed(0);

toFixed() gets as paramater how many decimal you wanna show.